# clientHold, autoRenewPeriod - Will this domain be available to register?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I'd like to buy a domain but it seems to be already taken. However, a WHOIS-lookup shows that it is not in a "normal state", and though I googled for the meanings of clientHold and autoRenewPeriod, I'm not an expert of this field so I don't completely understand what they mean. Here's the relevant digest from the WHOIS:

WHOIS Server: http://whois.udag.net;
Referral URL: http://www.united-domains.de;
Updated Date: 2015-07-10T05:15:52Z;
Creation Date: 2014-06-04T17:00:06Z;
Registry Expiry Date: 2016-06-04T17:00:06Z;
Sponsoring Registrar: united-domains AG;
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 1408;
Domain Status: clientHold;
Domain Status: autoRenewPeriod;

As I understand: The domain has expired a few days ago, it's expiry was automatically extended by the registrar, but its owner hasn't yet paid the fee for that(?) so if it doesn't get renewed by them, it will become free again in ~30-40 days. So if I'm lucky I can have it. :) Am I right, or its status cannot be told so accurately from this WHOIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A search for the term autoRenewPeriod turned up:

> This grace period is provided after a domain name registration period
>   expires and is extended (renewed) automatically by the registry. If
>   the registrar deletes the domain name during this period, the registry
>   provides a credit to the registrar for the cost of the renewal.

https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en

Comment: So as I interpret: The domain was registered by someone on 2014-06-04. Apparently for one year as on 2015-07-10 (After the 30-40 days of grace period provided by the registrar expired) the registry extended it for another grace period (Another couple of weeks maybe?) Then, if no-one acquires the domain name, it will become available to register again. (And the 2016-06-04 date is just something automatic default timestamp, having no meaning.)

Please someone correct me who knows it better.

Comment: It doesnt matter what it all means, you won't beable to prdict when it becomes available again, so you just have to either keep an eye on it yourself, write a script to keep trying to register through an API or use one of those backorder services.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep tabs on it then, thanks Steve! Anyway, today it's changed to redemptionPeriod. Time's working for me it seems. I hope no-one backordered it yet.

Comment: You are a newcomer to Stack Exchange.  It is good practise to accept an answer if it does answer your question.  Otherwise you are going to find that people won't answer your questions and you will sit on a reputation of 1 which means some people won't even look at the question.

Comment: It didn't really answer my question, the description you provided I have found long ago with google anyways. Yet I wanted to vote up to appreciate your help, however, for that I do not have the reputation yet. I want to be kind so accepted it now.